# Matching one of multiple paths (ACL)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, acl

I'm trying to re-implement an ACL system for a web app using Neo4j.

The application has a hierarchical Organization, the leaf nodes of which can own Tasks.

There are Roles, which have Permissions. Users can be assigned to a Role within an Organization or Task. Doing so should give them the permissions assigned to the Role within that Organization, any descendants, and any owned Tasks.

Additionally, some Users are assigned one-off Permissions on Organizations that are not part of a role.

I have setup the graph using hyper edges to model the User x Role x Organization and User x Permission x Organization intersections.

[image: Current data model]

I am trying to ask "Does the User have a given Permission on a given Task or Organization (whether through a Role or Permission assigned directly to a node)?"

I have partially answered it using:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(hyperedge:UserGroupRestriction)
        WHERE user.userId = 1
MATCH (hyperedge)-[:ON]->(restriction)-[:OWNS|:PARENT_OF*0..3]->(t:Task { id:2 }),
(hyperedge)-[:ROLE]->(role:Role)-[:CAN]->(p:Permission { name: 'tasks.edit' })
RETURN count(restriction) > 0 AS `allowed`
```

However this only works for the Role restriction, because I am only looking at the `MEMBER_OF` relation, which connects a User to a group restriction hyper edge. How do I modify the query so that I get a true result if they have the permission either trough a role membership or an assigned permission? The node Label for one-off permission hyper edges is `:UserPermissionRestriction`.

Thanks for any insight, I'm open to restructuring the graph if that makes sense since this is just early proof of concept.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and put here some Cypher query to create a initial data set and the expected result... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem completely, but I believe that the below query should work:

```
MATCH (user:User {userId : 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:CAN]->(oneOffPermission:UserPermissionRestriction)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(hyperedge:UserGroupRestriction)
OPTIONAL MATCH (hyperedge)-[:ON]->(restriction)-[:OWNS|:PARENT_OF*0..3]->(t:Task { id:2 }),
(hyperedge)-[:ROLE]->(role:Role)-[:CAN]->(p:Permission { name: 'tasks.edit' })
RETURN (count(oneOffPermission) >  0 OR count(restriction) > 0) AS `allowed`
```

I'm using `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of `MATCH` and trying to get the one-off permissions too.